# In Qt source, where to find the code for drawing controls on default Mac OS style?

Tags: qt, qt4.7, qslider, qstyle

I know QCommonStyle inherits QStyle, and QWindowsStyle inherits QCommonStyle, and QWindowsXPStyle inherits QWindowsStyle. If my application has a control (for example QSlider) and I debug it on Windows XP, then I can set a breakpoint on drawComplexControl() in qwindowsxpstyle.cpp to see how the QSlider is drawed. I can't find a file such as QMacStyle.cpp there, The QMacStyle inherits QWindowsStyle, but in qwindowsstyle.cpp, the code of drawComplexControl() seems not work for Mac styled controls. Where can I find the related source?